# Является ли это предложение сложносочиненным?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, сложное-предложение, однородные-члены, и

*О ком слагаете вы сказки балагурные, и песни непристойные, и всякую хулу?*

Answer (score 3):

*О ком слагаете вы **сказки** балагурные, и **песни** непристойные, и всякую **хулу**?*

Это не [сложносочинённое предложение](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#41), а простое предложение с однородными членами, соединёнными повторяющимся союзом ***и***, с одной грамматической основой – ***вы слагаете***.

[**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101)

> 6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то **запятая** ставится между всеми однородными членами: *Листья в поле **пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; Лён, и полотна, и пряжу** несут; А вокруг были **дым, и бой, и смерть*** (М. Г.); *Отрывистый и ломаный звук **метался, и прыгал, и бежал** куда-то в сторону от других* (Андр.); *Иные хозяева вырастили уже **вишни, или сирень, или жасмин*** (Ф); *Только **мальвы, да ноготки, да кручёный паныч** цвели кое-где по дворам* (Пан.); *Весь вечер Ленский был **рассеян, то молчалив, то весел вновь***(П.).

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Данное предложение является простым двусоставным распространённым предложением, осложнённым однородными дополнениями: *сказки, песни, хулу*.

Вот предложение с однородными подлежащими, но оно все равно является простым, так как в нем одна основа.
*И **кузнечики**, и **пчёлки**,

И весёлые **чижи**

Подпевают лягушатам

Эту песню от души...*
Наталия Овезова

Сложным предложением является такое предложение, в котором имеется две и более грамматических основ.

[Синтаксис. Осложнённые простые предложения. Общие понятия. Виды осложнений](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/443)

Comment: *Ajgy*, я подправила Ваш ответ и дополнила его примером и ссылкой. На сайте приветствуются полные ответы. Возможно, теперь его оценят. P. S. Если Вы считаете мое вмешательство ненужным (просто захотелось помочь), то можете правку откатить. P. P. S. Вон, у Александра — красота! Теперь и Ваш не хуже. Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо. Мне казалось, что ответ на вопрос получится вполне себе полный.